# I am having problems downloading and installing ubuntu macbook from this site

Tags: disk

The download says it cannot write to disk or driver.

Comment: There's very little actionable information here. When does this error appear? When you're downloading or when you're installing? Which MacBook is this? Some of the newer models will not allow other OSes to be installed. Help us help you by adding a bit more clarity, please :)

Comment: What site do you mean by "*this site*".  This is a user support site, and it's not where I'd download Ubuntu from (askubuntu.com is not on the official mirror list either).  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors